# Auto google sign in WebView React Native

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, webview, recaptcha

In a webview, from 'react-native-webview', I am showing a google ReCaptcha V2. On a normal browser, if you were to be logged in with google there is a higher chance that you get a one-click captcha, rather than a 'Select all squares that include X'. Is there a way that I can log them in without them having to do anything manually (when the WebView is mounts). Here is how I can show a regular ReCaptcha V2:

```
<head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Simple page</title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
```

Would I have to add there login info, which I will have from a different screen, to the WebView or do I have to add it to the HTML?